# Ros2 fails to build osrf_testing_tools_cpp with Visual Studio 15.8

Tags: ros2, colcon, windows10, compilation, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Is it correct that ROS2 on windows fails to build many of its default packages?
I **precisely** followed [these](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Windows-Development-Setup) steps to set up my environment for ROS2 bouncy and everything went fine. I installed opensplice, but had the same issues when trying to compile before I installed it. I checked my `PATH` as well.
When I run

```
colcon build --merge-install
```

every now and then, it fails to compile a package, which "exited with code 1". I then put an `AMENT_IGNORE` in the respecting folder and try again, just to see if it somehow can compile. But shouldn't these packages compile without failure?

To be precise, these packages fail to build: pluginlib, rviz, osrf, rcutils, demos, rmw, rcl_interfaces, std_srvs, std_msgs.
I also ignored the following: examples, examples_interfaces, rmw_connext, rmw_typesupport_connext.

Also, when I

```
cd \dev\ros2
call C:\opensplice67\HDE\x86_64.win64\release.bat
call install\local_setup.bat
ros2
```

the setup runs fine with no output, but I get "command not found" on ros2. Just as in this [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/294209/ros2-command-not-found-in-windows/).

Can anyone give me at least a hint? I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Program versions I use:

- Visual Studio: Community 2017 (15.8.1)
- OpenSplice: 6.7
- colcon: latest version as of now (I don't know how to find the version number)
- Python: 3.7
- Qt5: 5.10.0 (but I have also installed: 5.10.1, 5.11.0, 5.11.1)

It seems that when building packages fail to compile because they depend on each other but prevent their dependencies from being built while failing themselves. So when compiling step-by-step while adding one package each step (and unfortunately in the right but unknown order), as of now, at least some of the packages listed above compile.

While other packages compile because they only had missing dependencies, `osrf_testing_tools_cpp` gives me:

```
C:\dev\ros2>colcon build --packages-select osrf_testing_tools_cpp --merge-install --event-handler console_cohesion+
Starting >>> osrf_testing_tools_cpp
[4.039s] colcon.colcon_core.event_reactor ERROR Exception in event handler extension 'console_cohesion': 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2981: character maps to <undefined>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\colcon_core\event_reactor.py", line 78, in _notify_observers
retval = observer(event)
  File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\colcon_output\event_handler\console_cohesion.py", line 49, in __call__
content = h.read()
  File "c:\python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2981: character maps to <undefined>

Failed   <<< osrf_testing_tools_cpp     [ Exited with code 1 ]

Summary: 0 packages finished [3.67s]
  1 package failed: osrf_testing_tools_cpp
```

After downgrading to Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.7.6), not only osrf_testing_tools_cpp, but all packages not directly related to connext compile fine. Also, the build finishes and is not aborted (as was before). (See accepted answer)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302045/ros2-fails-to-build-osrf_testing_tools_cpp-with-visual-studio-15.8/) by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 200 on 2018-08-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-30**:
Bouncy is supposed to compile 'cleanly' on Win10, but things can of course change. Windows 10 is a bit of a 'moving target', so if any of the dependencies change versions then some things could break.

It might help if you could list the versions of some important components: VS, OpenSplice, ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-30**:
.., `colcon`, Python and Qt5.

But above all:

> Is it correct that ROS2 on windows fails to build

this is too vague. Without actual error messages (copy-pasted) we will only ever be able to guess at what might be wrong.

Please add more information to your question.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2018-08-30**:
colcon does not give me error messages! I am currently working my way through this. As of now, osrf_testing_tools_cpp fails to build with colcon but shows no reason. I will add my version numbers but they are exactly as in the tutorial...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-30**:
can you try building one of the failing packages with the following option added to the command line:

```
--event-handler console_cohesion+
```

That should provide you with a bit more information.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-30**:
That is why I asked the OP to report exact versions. Visual Studio is one such moving target I referred to earlier. It almost makes you wonder whether they don't have enough test coverage at MS when checking their VS releases.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-30**:
re: your latest edit: this could have nothing to do with it, but are you running a Windows 10 with a German locale configured?

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2018-08-30**:
@gvdhoorn: yes

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-30**:
If downgrading VS doesn't work (and I have a bit of a feeling it won't, but let's see), could you add a English (US) locale and switch to that. Then see if something changes? Be sure to (at least) log-out and then back in.

You should be able to revert back to German without issue afterwards.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-30**:
I'm not sure, but I believe the error colcon shows is not the real error, but the `console_cohesion` callback not being able to display the actual error due to a codec/locale issue.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-30**:\

> After downgrading to Visual Studio Community 2017 (15.7.6), osrf_testing_tools_cpp compiles fine.

glad things compile.

I'm wondering though if you won't run into the same problem again if any other pkg has trouble compiling.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2018-08-30**:
Thanks, with VS 15.7.6, at least osrf_testing_tools_cpp compiles fine. I somehow missed that I installed the wrong VS version. Will test now if that solved everything. Also, I updated my question.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2018-08-30**:
The locale thing seems odd to me. But yes, my output is from the console_cohesion failing to display the error. In the log files I had a long list of weird stuff... I will report, if I got stuck again.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-30**:
`colcon version-check` will tell you the versions of all `colcon` related packages as well as if they are up-to-date.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-30**:\

> The locale thing seems odd to me. But yes, my output is from the console_cohesion failing to display the error

then I expect future compilation/linker errors to result in the same problem, but let's see whether you post a new question.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-30**:
I am surprised that in the case of `osrf_testing_tools_cpp` failing to build there is no `stderr` output. Can you provide the content of the `log/build_<timestamp>` directory when you built just `osrf_testing_tools_cpp` and it failed without any output. That might help identifying a problem.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-30**:
Please consider trying https://github.com/colcon/colcon-output/pull/13 which aims to address the exception you experienced when using `--event-handler console_cohesion+`.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2018-08-31**:
@Dirk Thomas I can provide [my log files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4nFUQqcsnQDeVlIcFJqV1B1NWZIMDRXUGhQZUMtUmFMZlJR/view?usp=drivesdk) from when it failed.

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2018-08-31**:
Also, my build finishes now. Only a few connext related packages report a stderr output. I guess, I can ignore those as I do not want to use connext?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-31**:
Thank you for sharing the logs. I am pretty confident that the PR will fix this case: https://github.com/colcon/colcon-output/pull/13#issuecomment-417714567

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-08-31**:
Yes, you can ignore the warnings about Connext if you don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are also reports of the latest version of Visual Studio 2017 (15.8) having some new compiler errors.  There is an issue here: https://github.com/osrf/osrf_testing_tools_cpp/issues/15

I can confirm that Bouncy compiles on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 (15.0), try downgrading if possible.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2018-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcel Usai](https://answers.ros.org/users/17911/marcel-usai/) on 2018-08-30**:
@gvdhoorn: I updated my question.
@mjcarroll: I run version 15.8.1, will downgrade to 15.0 and try again.

Thank you for your time!